# how to tell Xcode about file indentation, etc. by file-macros

Tags: xcode, indentation

I often edit files from different sources. While I like my own indentation settings, I always would like to use the indentation style of the file I just have opened.

Is that possible somehow with Xcode? (Because right now, it always just uses my own settings.)

Or if not: Is it possible somehow via some macros in the source to tell Xcode about the current per-file indentation (similar as for Vim, Emacs).